# Google tracking code for Gravity Forms

Tags: php, wordpress, google-analytics, gravity-forms-plugin

I need to add Google event tracking to all the forms throughout my website. I have the following code in my functions file:

```
add_action("gform_after_submission", "gf_ga_tracking", 10, 2);
function gf_ga_tracking($entry, $form) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Forms', 'Submission', '<?php echo $form["title"]; ?>']);
});
</script>
<?php }
```

This code works but only on forms that use the Ajax text confirmation, however some of my forms have conditionals where they redirect to a PDF for download. On these forms I just get the red spinning icon and the user isn't redirected.

Is there a better function or hook that I can use to achieve the same result please? I want to limit the amount of plugins used for obvious reasons so I'd like to do this manually.

Answer (score 0):

You could listen for submissions in your main JavaScript file and then check for validation errors afterwords. Something like this:

```
//On load validation error
if ( jQuery('div.validation_error').length != 0 ){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Gravity Form', 'Validation Error',     jQuery('.gform_wrapper').find('form').attr('id'));
}

//AJAX Validation Errors
jQuery(document).on('gform_post_render', function(e, form_id){
    if ( jQuery('div.validation_error').length != 0 ){
        ga('send', 'event', 'Gravity Form', 'Validation Error', form_id);
    }
});

//Next/Prev page loaded
jQuery(document).on('gform_page_loaded', function(e, form_id, current_page){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Gravity Form', 'Next/Prev Page', form_id + ' (' + current_page + ')');
});

//Submission attempt
jQuery(document).on('submit', '.gform_wrapper form', function(){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Gravity Form', 'Submit (Attempt)', jQuery('.gform_wrapper').find('form').attr('id'));
});

//Successful form submission
jQuery(document).on("gform_confirmation_loaded", function(e, form_id){
    ga('send', 'event', 'Gravity Form', 'Submit (Success)', form_id);
});
```

There is also a WordPress plugin (which I have not used): https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravity-forms-google-analytics-event-tracking/

Doesn't seem like it would track all of the events above, but could be considered.